# OpenLDAP: Why would you ever use refreshOnly for replication?

Tags: replication, openldap

I'm reading about OpenLDAP replication and I don't understand why you would use refreshOnly mode vs. refreshAndPersist mode.

I've tried to do some searching online, but wasn't able to find any discussion on the benefits (if any) of refreshOnly.

[This page says](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch7/#ol-syncrepl-mm) "In this configuration, assuming that a refreshAndPersist type of synchronization is used (it is not clear why you would even want to think about using refreshOnly but it is possible), then a write (modify) to any master will be immediately propagated to all the other masters (providers) acting in their slave (consumer) role."

But's it's referring to Multi-Master replication and doesn't say anything similar for Provider/Consumer replication.

Is there any reason why I should ever consider refreshOnly for OpenLDAP replication?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, I think this might be better served on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `refreshOnly` if you wanted to completely control when replication took place, e.g. every midnight. You would use `refreshAndPersist` when you want replication to be continuous and as instantaneous as possible.